# Get Current Location on external login using google in mvc5 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, asp.net-identity

I fall in this scenario where I need to store the Location of the user upon  his login using mvc. Since Mvc 5 supports external Login is it possible to get the location of the user when he logged in using his google account as an external account authentication in an MVC 5 App...

Comment: Good question no idea,  here is googles MVC sample project try and dig around in this https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/tree/master/Calendar.ASP.NET.MVC5

Comment: link appreciated. I came to play around in here since Google has that Api on Javascript, why does it does not expose it on there Oauth for .Net??

Comment: you could probably get the users location from the Google+ api, but that will only work if they have a google+ account.   I wonder if the JavaScript library you speak of doesn't do some kind of Google magic with the users IP address to return the location.

Comment: thats what i think also. it is added task for the dev side to get it using another request while they can add it on the OAuth in such way we can access it?? Im looking for that.. I didnt bookmarked that topic but it is here on SO.

Comment: The Google .Net client library is open source you could add it yourself if you think its something that others would want.   https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client